# Testing AngularJS with teaspoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, jasmine, teaspoon

I am trying to use teaspoon with Jasmine suite to test my AngularJS scripts in Ruby on Rails. While running "rake teaspoon", I am getting the below error -

```
Starting the Teaspoon server...
Teaspoon running default suite at http://127.0.0.1:41029/specs/default
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
Error: ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template teaspoon/suite/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
```

Any pointers?